# JQuery Find and replace within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace all font awesome icon within a certain div.

Here is my code:

```
$( '#icons' ).find( '.fa' ).each( function() {
  if( $( this ).hasClass( 'fa-adjust' ) ){
    $( this ).attr( 'class' , 'fa fa-circle' );
  } else if( $( this ).hasClass( 'fa-circle' ) ){
    $( this ).attr( 'class' , 'fa fa-adjust' );
  }
});
```

What I would like to do is swap `fa-adjust` with `fa-circle` within the div `icons`.

Comment: what is the problem with your own code ?

Comment: it is not swapping the classes.  i forgot to mention, that the classes could be several div's below `icons`... does this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function. It can toggle several classes:

```
$( '#icons' ).find( '.fa' ).toggleClass('fa-adjust fa-circle');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it straight away, as you can't have duplicate ids. Is `icons` a class?

```
$('.fa-adjust').removeClass("fa-adjust").addClass("fa-circle");
```

Comment: No, `icons` is a div so I want to swap all of the `fa-adjust` and `fa-circle` within the div `icons`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#icons').find('.fa.fa-adjust, .fa.fa-circle').toggleClass('fa-adjust fa-circle');
```

But why do you have to do it with JS rather than modify the markup?

Comment: I am getting the updates from an ajax call and would like to change the icon to reflect the refreshed states.

Comment: Got it. You don't have to call `each` because `toggleClass` will perform a so-called **implicit iteration** - jQuery automatically iterates over all the elements in a selection.